# how to move Tmux panes

Tags: tmux

I like to work with 3 tmux panes. one horizontal pane at the upper half of the screen and two more panes at the bottom half. These panes are split vertically.

[image: tmux pane image]

There are cases where I would like to take the last pane and make it go from top to bottom. like this:

[image: target tmux pane image]

How can I achieve this? using [ctrl+b ctrl+o] and [ctrl+b space] did not reach the desired position and is cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably an easier way, but what you can do is arrange the panes manually in each of the two configurations, noting each layout in a variable with e.g.:

```
layout1=$(tmux list-windows -F '#{window_layout}')
```

This holds a string something like:

```
5f2f,80x23,0,0[80x11,0,0,0,80x11,0,12{39x11,0,12,1,40x11,40,12,2}]
```

which you must not alter in any way as the first number is a checksum of the rest of the string.

Once you have the two strings you can set a binding to set that layout using `select-layout`, or by giving the command from the shell where you have the variables:

```
tmux select-layout "$layout1"
```

You might find it easier to write a small helper script, say `mtmux` to toggle between the layouts:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/56343223/5008284
# toggle between 2 layouts, previously saved
layout1='5f2f,80x23,0,0[80x11,0,0,0,80x11,0,12{39x11,0,12,1,40x11,40,12,2}]'
layout2='093c,80x23,0,0{39x23,0,0[39x11,0,0,0,39x11,0,12,4],40x23,40,0,3}'
layout="$(tmux list-windows -F '#{window_layout}')"
case "$layout" in
*80x11*)    new=$layout2 ;;
*)          new=$layout1 ;;
esac
tmux select-layout "$new"
tmux display-panes
exit 0
```

and have a binding, say control-L, to run this shell:

```
    bind-key -n C-l run-shell 'mtmux'
```